# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) on line with let

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, parse-error

I get

> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

on the line with `| i > j = do swap axs p j`

```
apartition :: Ord a => STArray s Int a -> Int -> Int -> ST s Int
apartition axs p q = do 
  x <- readArray axs p
  let loop i j
    | i > j = do swap axs p j
                 return j
    | otherwise = do u <- readArray axs i
                     if u < x 
                       then do loop (i + 1) j 
                       else do swap axs i j
                            loop i (j − 1)
  loop (p + 1) q
```

I am really confused about the cause of this, could someone clear things up for me?

Comment: @SimonShine: this is a `do` block, so the `in` is not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an indentation error, you need to place the guard at least one character to the right of the start of the definition of `loop`, so:

```
apartition :: Ord a => STArray s Int a -> Int -> Int -> ST s Int
apartition axs p q = do 
  x <- readArray axs p
  let loop i j
       | i > j = do swap axs p j
                    return j
       | otherwise = do u <- readArray axs i
                        if u < x 
                        then do loop (i + 1) j 
                        else do swap axs i j
                                loop i (j - 1)
  loop (p + 1) q
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the quick response! The solution worked. Is there any specific reason for this behaviour of the parser?

I will accept the answer once the timer ends!

Comment: @MisterBabu: `let` (in either a `do` statement or `let`…`in`… expression) begins a *layout block*, just like `case`…`of`…, `where`, and `do`, because `let` may contain multiple definitions. The `let` statement in the corrected code is interpreted as `let { loop i j | i > j = … | otherwise = …; };`. In your original code, it was `let { loop i j; };` + *indent* + `| i > j = …`, which doesn’t parse. My preference in this case is to write `let` + *newline* + *indent* instead, just like your outer `do` block, so this alignment doesn’t matter. (The same could apply to your inner `do` blocks.)